# Is it safe to permit user add content using Tiny MCE?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tinymce

I want to add **Tiny MCE** in my rails app, so each user can add a post and styling the text using this tool, there is a danger if i permit that because when i show the user's post it's necessary to use something like this

```
<%= post.content.html_safe %>
```

Comment: Had to delete my answer. I think you are right that it could be dangerous.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but I thought I would answer nevertheless if someone is looking for an answer. Using html_safe (or raw) when displaying user-added content is not always a great idea, as it makes you vulnerable to attacks (if we assume your users aren't all good guys ;)) but there is a rails helper called sanitize (http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/SanitizeHelper.html#method-i-sanitize) which does just what you need, and it works with the input from a tinymce editor. you can just use it like so:

```
<%= sanitize post.content %>
```